# How to change Docker's default Image storage location in WSL2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

How can I change the default location for storing Docker images in Windows? I currently have Docker installed on my `C:` drive, and the images are stored in the following location:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data.
```

I want to change the default location to my `D:` drive. I am using WSL2 as the backend for Docker, and I have read that I can use the `.wslconfig` file to configure Docker. However, I am not sure how to set up the `.wslconfig` file to change the default image location. My WSL2 installation is located on my `D:` drive, which I installed from the Microsoft Store.

I'm using `Docker version 20.10.21` and these are wsl specs

```
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22000.1335
```

I'm using `Ubuntu` distro in `WSL`, and `Docker Desktop v.4.15.0`
I tried making some changes in `.wslconfig` but there was no option for storage or something.

Comment: Not running Windows ATM, but I think you can config this in `%USERPROFILE%\.docker\daemon.json` with something similar to the line `{ "data-root": "D:\\path\\to\\your\\docker\\data\\directory" }`

Answer (score 1):

Caveats/Preface:

- I've tried this and it works, but I cannot guarantee that *long-term* it will continue to work.  There's the *potential* that something will break when Docker Desktop upgrades in the future.
- In general I don't recommend registry hacks, but I'm not aware of another way to do this.  Other than the previous caveat, this seems fairly safe.
- No, there's no `.wslconfig` option for changing the location of a distribution.

With that in mind, here's what I did to move `docker-desktop-data` to the `D:` drive:

- Create the directory.  I'll use `D:\wsl\docker-desktop-data` as an example.
- Stop Docker Desktop by right-clicking on the status bar icon and *Quit Docker Desktop*.
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  ```
- Confirm the location (`BasePath`) and registry key (`PSChildName`) of the `docker-desktop-data` via:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ |
      ForEach-Object {
          (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH)
      } | Where-Object {
          $_.DistributionName -eq "docker-desktop-data"
      }
  ```
- Move `ext4.vhdx` from the `BasePath` directory identified above to the `D:\wsl\docker-desktop-data` directory.
- In `regedit`, navigate to:

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss
  ```
- Find the subkey matching the `PSChildName` from above.
- Modify the `BasePath` to point to `\\?\D:\wsl\docker-desktop-data`
- Restart Docker Desktop
- Test that your existing images are still available by running one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Docker Desktop versions, e.g. `v4.19.0`, there is the option "**Disk Image location**" in Settings (`Settings` -> `Resources` -> `Advanced`) for that.

BUT **it still does NOT work** as it supposed to do.

Please, read my [comment](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13345#issuecomment-1551971857) *(detailed guide)* how to do it manually, until the issue will be fixed.

**NOTE:** This option is available for Docker with WSL 2 backend. Check that box "**Use the WSL 2 based engine**" is checked on the `Settings` -> `General` tab